# Не выводит значения из файла

Tags: c++

Не выводит два значения из файла, в консоли просто вывод 0 0, тогда как в файле 123 75.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("1.txt", "r", stdin);

    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << b << " " << a;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы проверили, что возвращает `freopen`? Что файл `1.txt` есть, находится именно в **текущем** рабочем каталоге? Например, что выводит `cout << errno`? Ну и безотносительно к вопросу, мне вообще не нравится смесь С и С++.

Comment: Да, "1.txt" находится в рабочем каталоге. Можете объяснить про смесь С и С++? Мне как новичку очень не понятен этот момент. "errno" также выводит 0.

Comment: Тут ошибка в первой же строке - игнорирование нового дескриптора потока, возвращаемого `freopen`. А вообще открывайте файл посредством `::std:ifstream`